# Создать метод, возвращающий конкретный тип потомка обобщенного типа

Tags: java, generics

Столкнулся с непониманием между мной и явой в вопросе вывода типа. А именно: не могу написать метод, возвращающий не просто коллекцию, а конкретного потомка коллекции.

```
public static <T, L extends Collection<T>> L genList(){
   return (L)new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

По задумке, этот метод вернет потомка Collection, причем все методы потомка будут доступны.
На практике, этот код вообще не работает, пока не кастанешь в L. А если кастанешь - распрощаешься с методами потомка.
Как же так, если по-идее ArrayList является потомком Collection?

На код выше меня сподвиг рабочий код:

```
public static <T, L extends Collection<T>> L getCollection(L list, T t1, T t2, T t3){
    list.add(t1);
    list.add(t2);
    list.add(t3);
    return list;
}
```

Смысл этого кода в том же - получить объект, с которым можно работать, как с коллекцией. А на выходе получить этот же объект с сохранением типа.

Почему этот код работает, а код выше - нет? Не пойму.

Ну и на закуску очень странный для меня код шреденгера, который работает и не работает одновременно.

```
public static <T, L extends Collection<T>> L genCollection(Supplier<L> gen, T t1, T t2, T t3){
    L list = gen.get();
    list.add(t1);
    list.add(t2);
    list.add(t3);
    return list;
}
```

Отличие от предыдущего кода в том, что мы на вход подаем не коллекцию, а лямбду, возвращающую коллекцию. И, в зависимости от того, что мы туда передадим, у нас код будет возвращать как конкретный тип, так и обобщенный.

Возьмем к примеру, следующий тип:

```
public class ItWorks<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public void itWorks(){
        System.out.println("It works!");
    }
}
```

И применим к нему методы:

```
getCollection(new ItWorks<>(), 1,2,3).itWorks();
genCollection(ItWorks::new,1,2,3);
genCollection(() -> new ItWorks<>(),1,2,3).itWorks();
```

Первый и третий методы возвращают сам тип, а второй - обобщенную коллекцию.
Что не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В java generics invariant-ны, к сожалению.
И еще их постигает type erasure,

В scala (covariant/contravariant) и kotlin (in/out), которые работают на JVM это улучшили:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Вообще тема сложная.

---

Есть время компиляции (при которой происходит проверка типов) и время исполнения программы.

Во время исполнения классы есть, а дженериков уже нет: `Collection` и `ArrayList` отличаются, а `Collection<String>` от `Collection<Item>` не отличается.

При этом если куда-то в качестве `Collection`-а пришел `ArrayList`, то всё нормально, будут работать методы, переопределенные для ArrayList.
И скастить в `ArrayList` тоже получится (хотя увлекаться не стоит).

Есть время компиляции типы проверяются более основательно, с дженериками.
`getCollection` компилится, т. к. на входе и выходе один и тот же объект одинакового типа `L`.

`genList` без кастинга не компилится, т. к. (хотя и `ArrayList` и `L` являются подтипами `Collection`) компилятор не может доказать взаимозаменяемость `ArrayList` и `L`.
Предположим, в конкретном вызове `genList` захочется `L` как `Set` (он же тоже подтип `Collection`), а вы ему `ArrayList` возвратите.
Эту ошибку компилятор не пропускает. А если сделать каст `(L)`, то компилятор успокоится. А потом исполнение упадет где-то, т. к. окажется, что `ArrayList` не умеет быть `Set`.

---

> применяем genList в методах, где тип выводится однозначно, таким образом он передается в метод genList()

Чтобы создать коллекцию нужного типа, нужен конструктор/фабрика для этого типа. Это можно наблюдать в `genCollection(Supplier`.

Tип не передается, у `genList()` аргументов нет.

Можно в `genList()` передать `Class<...>` вместо фабрики:

- и сделать реестр фабрик, из которого по классу брать фабрику
- или применить к классу рефлекшн

Comment: я знаю о type erasure, но не понимаю, почему он не сработал в getCollection() - там на выходе все же получается объект исходного типа, без затирания.

Comment: добавил подробней

Comment: Объяснение хорошее.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как сказать компилятору, что я хочу на выходе получать то, что я создаю внутри.

И при этом ограничить множество типов потомками супер-типа коллекции.

Comment: `<T> Collection<T> genList()` пойдет?

Comment: `<T> List<T> genList()`; что-то я не понимаю...

Comment: Помешает ли вам где-то, если возвращать `List`?

Comment: так весь смысл был в том, что я не знаю, какая коллекция подается на вход, но ее нужно сохранить. Раз этого нельзя, то и остальное бессмысленно.

Comment: в примере с `genList` на входе ничего нет

Comment: То есть, ты хочешь сказать, что он затирает тип при передаче?

Просто моя логика такова: мы применяем genList в методах, где тип выводится однозначно, таким образом он передается в метод genList() и создает коллекцию нужного типа.

Comment: 1) в последних мессаджах про затирание не говорил 2) чтобы создать коллекцию нужного типа, нужен конструктор/фабрика для этого типа. Это можно наблюдать в `genCollection(Supplier` 3) тип не передается, у `genList()` аргументов нет 4) можно в genList() передать `Class<...>` вместо фабрики; и сделать реестр фабрик, из которого по классу брать фабрику; или применить к классу рефлекшн